# Cannot printk user space string parameter when intercepting a syscall

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm trying to intercept a Linux syscall to record all opened filename to a log file. but there's a problem: it failed to printk the filename in user space. Here are the codes of fake syscall function:

```
static inline long hacked_open(const char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode)
{
    char buf[256];
    buf[255] = '\0';

    long res = strncpy_from_user(buf, filename, 255);
    if (res > 0)
        printk("%s\n", buf);
    else
        printk("---err len : %ld ---\n", res);

    orig_func a = (orig_func)orig_open;

    return a(filename, flags, mode);
}
```

after I loaded the kernel module, dmesg showed a lot of message as:

`---err len : -14---`

I've tried copy_from_user and printk the filename directly, but they all doesn't work.

Comment: Is this triggered by a program of your own calling `open()`, or random activity on the system?  It could be that there really is some buggy program on your machine calling `open()` with an invalid pointer for `filename`.  If so, not much to be done except log it if you like and let it fail.

Comment: I tried intercepting another syscall ( mkdir ) to printk pathname, but it still doesn't work. so I think the problem is nothing to do with syscall open .

Comment: So perhaps your interception code is messed up, and what you're getting in the `filename` argument is not what userspace passed to the system call.  You could confirm this with a test program that invokes the system call; compare the pointer it passed in, and the pointer that your handler receives.

Comment: No. I don't think the interception code is messed up, it worked well when it called the origin syscall function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by myself.

the parameters of hacked_open are wrong.

the correct hacked_openat should be :

`asmlinkage long hacked_openat(struct pt_regs *regs)`

and we can get filename from user-space like this:

`int nRet = strncpy_from_user(filename, (char __user *)regs->si, 1024);`